# How do I get arrays to display ascending and descending

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to stackoverflow and I have been given an assessment to complete but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to. I have the first part working fine but the second part with the array isn't working plus I want it to display the array in ascending and descending order. Any help would be great thanks

```
// Test4.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.

//

/* For this assessment I am required to create a menu system consisting of 3 options 1 to generate a username, 2 to sort an array in ascending and descending order and 3 to exit.


The menu should be displayed as shown


1. String Functions

2. Array Functions

3. Exit

*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

// Here are the methods I will use

void display_menu();

void create_name();

void menu_act_on_choice(int choice_in);
void generate_and_display_name(string name_in);

//global double array

double calcTimes[] = { 21.23,23.45,23.71,22.22,24.12,21.23,21.23,21.45 };

void display_menu()
{
  /*
do
display menu options
prompt for and read value for choice
if choice <> 4 (quit option)
call menu_act_on_choice passing value of choice
while choice is not equal to 4 (quit option)
*/
  // local variables
  int choice = 0;

  do
  {
system("cls");
cout << "Make your selection from the following options" << endl
  << "1. String Functions" << endl
  << "2. Array Functions" << endl
  << "3. Exit" << endl;
cout << "> ";
cin >> choice;
menu_act_on_choice(choice);
} // end do

  while (choice != 4);

} // end method

void menu_act_on_choice(int choice_in)
{
  switch (choice_in)
{
  case 1:
  create_name();
  break;

  case 2:
  void array_length();
  break;

  case 3:
  break;
}// end switch

}

void create_name()
{
  /*
prompt for first name and second name
using getline read in name in format first name and last name
ignore white space
call create_name() passing name as parameter
*/
  // local variables
  string name = "";
 
cout << "Enter your full name: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, name);
generate_and_display_name(name);
} // end method

void generate_and_display_name(string name_in)
{
  // local variables
  string string1;
  int position = 0;
  string string2;

  // add first character to string 1
string1.assign(name_in, 0, 1);

  // find position of space
position = name_in.find(" "); // position of first space

  // assign lastname to string 2, position +1 to end of string
string2.assign(name_in, position + 1, name_in.length());

  //concatenate both strings
string1.append(string2);

  // Print name
cout << "Your username is " << string1 << endl;
cout << "Press any key to return to the menu ";
cin.ignore();
} // end method

void array_length()
{
  // stage 1 find the total size of the array in bytes

  int stage1 = sizeof(calcTimes);

cout << "The array is " << stage1 << " bytes" << endl;

 

  // stage 2 find the size of a single element

  int stage2 = sizeof(calcTimes[0]);  // or sizeof(int)

cout << "A single element is " << stage2 << " bytes" << endl;

 

  // stage 3 calculate how many elements stage 1 / stage 2

 

  int stage3 = (stage1 / stage2);

cout << "There are " << stage3 << " elements" << endl;

}

 

int main()

{

display_menu();

}
```

Comment: You can use `std::sort` to sort a container/array.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

Example:

```
#include <array>       // std::begin, std::end
#include <algorithm>   // std::sort
#include <functional>  // std::less, std::greater

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double calcTimes[] = { 21.23,23.45,23.71,22.22,24.12,21.23,21.23,21.45 };
    

    // ascending order (std::less<>{} is the default and can be left out)
    std::sort(std::begin(calcTimes), std::end(calcTimes), std::less<>{});

    // print the result
    for(double value : calcTimes) std::cout << value << '\n';


    // decending order
    std::sort(std::begin(calcTimes), std::end(calcTimes), std::greater<>{});

    // print the result
    for(double value : calcTimes) std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Hi Ted, where do I put this as I don't have an int main up the top? Thanks

Comment: @MarcStewart You're welcome! You could put the sorting right before you want to display the array.

Comment: Can I show you my code that I have currently. Thanks

Comment: @MarcStewart Sure, you can update your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67636585/edit) it if there is something missing in it. While you're on it, make it into a [mre]. Only include just enough code to show the problematic part. We don't need to see all the code that is already working as expected.

Comment: Hi Ted, here is my issue void sort_array_ascending()
{
    {
    double calcTimes[8] = { 21.23,23.45,23.71,22.22,24.12,21.23,21.23,21.45 };
    int i, j, temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (calcTimes[i]<calcTimes[i+1])
            temp = calcTimes[i];
            calcTimes[i] = calcTimes[i + 1];
            calcTimes[i + 1] = temp;

    }
}

Comment: I want under the elements in the array I want it to show the numbers in ascending and descending order plus for the last option I want to exit the console.

Comment: @MarcStewart Isn't that exactly what my code does? [Look here](https://godbolt.org/z/5M3Exo3Pq)

Comment: Where abouts do I put it?

Comment: You create functions to display the array and call the appropriate sort function before printing it. Right now you only have one array function, `array_length`. I'm guessing you want to be able to do more than just checking the length? If so, add those missing functions.

Comment: So would I do display_ascending and insert the ascending code then display_descending and insert the descending code?

Comment: @MarcStewart Yes, that sounds like a good plan.

Comment: That worked! Now for the last option how do I get it to enter any key to exit?

Comment: @MarcStewart Right now, the menu will keep showing up until you select `4` (because of the loop condition `while (choice != 4)`).  If you want _any_ key (except `1` and `2`) to stop the loop from looping, you could change the condition to `while(choice == '1' || choice == '2')`.

Comment: @MarcStewart Did my answer answer your original question?